# Why do I get the "plot.new has not been called yet" error with the `box` function in RShiny?

Tags: plot, shiny

```r
# USER INTERFACE ####
ui <-  fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    tabPanel(
      "TAB1",   
      mainPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "Subtab1",
          fluidRow(
            "TEF",
            column(
              12, 
              box(6, "CE", plotOutput("plot1")),
              box(6, "CO", plotOutput("plot2"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl))
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error

```r
Error in box(6, "CE", plotOutput("plot1")) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: You cannot have a navbarPage inside a fluidPage (nor the other way around). Plus, `box(6,` should be `box(width=6,` because the width is not the first argument of the `box` function. After these 2 changes, it worked well for me.

Comment: The `navbarPage` worked fine before  the `box` was added

Comment: Can you show what changes should I make? I want the code

Comment: I removed the `navbarPage` but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

I did not have this error but I had another.

To correct it, I added the `width=` argument to the `box` function. Note that your are note supposed to use several `Page` functions in one shiny app. You are supposed to either chose `fluidPage` OR `navbarPage` OR `shinydashboardPage`. Only the last one enables you to correctly use the `box` function from {shinydashboard}.

```
ui <-  fluidPage(
    tabPanel(
      "TAB1",   
      mainPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "Subtab1",
          fluidRow(
            "TEF",
            column(
              12, 
              # Note that to correctly use the `shinydashboard::box` function,
              # you are supposed to use shinydashboardPage instead of fluidPage
              box(width=6, "CE", plotOutput("plot1")),
              box(width=6, "CO", plotOutput("plot2"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
)
```

Comment: I still get the error

Comment: i really don't know what else to do, it works fine for me